# How can I check whether uploaded file is image or video using php?

Tags: image, file, video

I've this code for handling uploaded multiple images. I want to upload and handle videos also. How can I check whether uploaded file is image or video? Please note that I want to handle multiple video files.

```
<?php
include('selectdb2.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    if(isset($_FILES['file']))
    {
        $count = 0;
        $errors= array();

        foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
        {
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'][$key];  

            $enc_id= $_POST['form_id'].$_POST['name3'];
            $md5folder = md5($enc_id); 
            $upload_path ="uploads/".$md5folder;

            if(!is_dir($upload_path))
            {
                mkdir($upload_path, 0777, true);
            }

            if(empty($errors)==true)
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$upload_path.'/'.$file_name);
            }

        }
.....
.....
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check out extension of file name because you can not trust content type of uploaded file. It can spoof by clients. So you have create array list -also know as white list- for extension list of images and videos.

For instance:

```
$allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
$filename = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Yeah sure..Thanks..I'll be adding this code..But how can I hand execute a code if  the uploaded file is a video and the above code(in the question) if it is an image..I'm really new to php but doing advanced things :p